# What's the usual way of handling animations within ListView cells?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I have a `GridView` where I'm doing animations on sub-views of the grid cells.  My problem is that the `View` recycling behavior means that on a long fling down the list, my `ObjectAnimators` sometimes end up pointed at the wrong `View`.

I've got my adapter implementing `AbsListView.RecyclerListener` and I'm getting the associated events, but detaching the `Animator` is proving more difficult than I expected.  I tried `animator.setTarget(null)`, but that got all crashy.  I tried pointing it at a dummy object with a no-op setter, but that didn't go very well either.  I think `Animators` get grouchy when you try to change the target out from under them.

I had somewhat better luck calling `animator.end()` and just ignoring the recycle events completely, but in both cases I still get some flicker that I'd really like to eliminate.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to reconnect a long-running `Animator` back up to a `View` when the associated data swings back into the viewport in some kind of reasonable way.

What's the best method of detaching and re-attaching `ObjectAnimators` to `ListView` or `GridView` cells?